# XAML window inside winforms program

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml

When I use a button on a form for Winforms to open a window made in XAML the first time it works with no issues, then I close the window and re-click the button, but on the `InitializeComponent()` for the window being created I get an exception with the message, `"The Application object is being shut down"`.

```
//code on button press is this 
var rs = new RestoreSettings();
rs.Show();
```

I have tried hosting it as a user control inside an `element host` still the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal application both the WinForms and WPF environment is kickstarted by an `Application` type, which is typically called from the `Main` method.

Here this does not happen for the WPF environment, which causes problems. If you want to show a WPF window from a WinForms application you need to boot up the dispatcher. Best to do this in a new thread so it can be shut down as many times as you want:

```
private void ShowWpfWindow()
{
    // This delegate is executed in new thread
    ThreadStart showWindow = () =>
    {
        var window = new RestoreSettingsWindow(); // your window to show

        // making sure that the thread can exit when the window is closed
        window.Closed += (sender, e) => Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        window.Show();

        // Starts the dispatcher in the new thread and does not let the thread exit.
        // This call is returned when the window is closed (due to the Closed event handler)
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    };

    // Creating and starting an STA thread for the WPF window
    Thread wpfThread = new Thread(showWindow);
    wpfThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    wpfThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    wpfThread.Start();
}
```